# Erlang converting timestamp to Year-Month-DayTHour:Min:SecZ format

Tags: erlang

Hi I want to convert erlang:now(). timestamp output :

```
> erlang:now().
{1425,589373,955614}
```

into Year-Month-DayTHour:Min:SecZ format. Whats the fastes way to do it?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, `os:timestamp()` might be more appropriate than `erlang:now()`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17399544/113848).

Comment: ok. but it returns in same format right ?

Comment: Yes, the return format is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure that this is *fastest* way, but I'd try this one:

```
{{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Minute, Second}} = calendar:now_to_datetime(erlang:now()),
StrTime = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~4..0w-~2..0w-~2..0wT~2..0w:~2..0w:~2..0w",[Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second])).
```

Comment: if you want the local time you should use `calendar:now_to_local_time(erlang:now())`

Comment: This doesnt add the timezone in the end

Answer (score 2):

The format you're interested in is known as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If you're looking for more than a quick conversion, I've liked this library from Sean Sawyer: https://github.com/seansawyer/erlang_iso8601

Answer (score 2):

The [erlsci iso8601](https://github.com/erlsci/iso8601) library does a fine job of formatting (and parsing) dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use special libraries for parsing and formatting dates. For example [tempo](https://github.com/selectel/tempo) or [qdate](https://github.com/choptastic/qdate).